# Split string by first white space

Tags: javascript, string, split

I want to split string in array based just on first white space in string.

Like this:

```
var name = "Jone Doe Doone";
var res = ["Jone", "Doe Doone"];
```

Comment: Why don't you use ... `indexOf()` then split using a `substring()` ?

Comment: Use split(" ",1) to get the first name and then use replace() to get the remaing string. var Name = "Jone Doe Doone"; var res1 = Name.split(" ",1); var res2 = Name.replace(res1 + " ", ""); var res = [res1, res2];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example where I have used `indexOf()` to find the first space and then return with a splitted array with `substring()`

```js
function splitAtFirstSpace(str) {
  if (! str) return [];
  var i = str.indexOf(' ');
  if (i > 0) {
    return [str.substring(0, i), str.substring(i + 1)];
  }
  else return [str];
}

console.log(splitAtFirstSpace("Jone Doe Doone"));
console.log(splitAtFirstSpace("BooDoone"));
console.log(splitAtFirstSpace("Doe Doone"));
```

Comment: `const` is not yet widely supported, I doubt that he is using any transpirel.

Comment: @Cristy well ... if you check the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Browser_compatibility) ... it's a fair consideration. But I use that as habit. Replaced to `var` then.

Comment: Yes, on desktop support is ok, but on mobile it's pretty bad.

Answer (score -3):

Simple.

```
function splitFirst(s) {
  var firstW = s.indexOf(" ");
  if (firstW < 0) {
    return s;
  }
  var array = [];
  array.push(s.substring(0, firstW));
  array.push(s.substring(firstW, s.length - 1));
  return array;
}
```

Note: Javascript coding convention says variables have to start with lowercase.

Comment: That removes the second space, combining the second and third words. Also doesn't handle if there are additional words after the third.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: It cuts off the last character in the final array element. If you change `s.length - 1` to `s.length` in the second `.push` that should fix it.

Answer (score -4):

Try the following answer.

```
var Name = "Jone Doe Doone";
var result = [Name.split(" ")[0]];
result.push(Name.substr(Name.split(" ")[0].length).trim());
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I have updated my answer.